# In Marie.js how would I go about doing an if statement and loop for the following pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode, marie

```
max = 0
value = 0

LOOP
    INPUT value

    IF (value == 0)
    EXIT LOOP
    ENDIF

    IF (value > max)
           max = value
    ENDIF
ENDLOOP

PRINT max
STOP
```

I am using https://marie.js.org/ but i'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to do an if statement. I've attempted to use skipcond. I'm also struggling a bit with the endless loop. Any help to get me started off would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert the pseudo code to the ***if-goto*** style of assembly language & machine code.

```
if a then
   b
endif
```

translates into

```
    if !a then goto endif1
    b
endif1,
```

---

Second, translate your pseudo code ***variables*** into Marie assembly language/machine code variables.

For example, you have an integer `max` in the pseudo code, so in the data area put:

```
max, dec 0
```

---

Finally, translate each line of if-goto code into assembly.

---

Conditional tests `if a < b goto` are done by comparison using subtraction.  So, load `a` into the accumulator, subtract `b`, which sets the condition codes, and then do a `SkipCond` and goto to skip or not skip code you want to execute.

---

Marie.js has a number of simple examples.  Look at the multiplication example, to see data/variable declarations, conditional branches, loops, input, output.

Comment: Got it done and dusted using your advice and the examples available. Thanks!